# Celery: Perform tasks one-at-a-time

Tags: python, celery

Is there a way to get all tasks being added to Celery to perform one-after-the-next?

I have a bunch of celery tasks and they can happen at any time (they're triggered by users) and I would like for them to not all run at the same time as to lighten the load on my server.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to have a dedicated worker with concurrency set to 1, subscribed to a "special" queue. Then you send your tasks that you want to run sequentially to this queue. [celery multi](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/celery/bin/multi.html) (creates multiple workers on the same node) is especially useful for such use-cases.